wrapping iterator in async stream type mismatched
I would like to wrap an iterator like this with an async stream:
Feed::from(vec![Event::A]);

There is other use case, e.g. wrapping another async stream.
I define the wrapper struct:
use async_stream::stream;
use futures::StreamExt;
use futures_core::stream::Stream;

pub enum Event {
    A,
}

pub trait Generator<Event> {
    async fn next(&mut self) -> Event;
}

pub struct Feed<T>
where
    T: Stream<Item = Event> + Send + Sync,
{
    pub event_iterator: T,
}

impl<T> Generator<Event> for Feed<T>
where
    T: Stream<Item = Event> + Send + Sync + Unpin,
{
    async fn next(&mut self) -> Event {
        self.event_iterator.next().await.unwrap()
    }
}

impl<T> Feed<T>
where
    T: Stream<Item = Event> + Send + Sync + Unpin,
{
    pub fn from<IntoIter, Iter>(market_iterator: IntoIter) -> Self
    where
        IntoIter: IntoIterator<Item = Event, IntoIter = Iter> + Send + Sync + 'static,
        Iter: Iterator<Item = Event> + std::marker::Send + Sync,
        Event: Send + Sync + 'static,
    {
        let s = stream! {
            for value in market_iterator.into_iter() {
                yield value;
            }
        };

        Self { event_iterator: s }
    }

    pub fn new(s: T) -> Self {
        Self { event_iterator: s }
    }
}

error:
mismatched types
expected type parameter `T`
           found struct `AsyncStream<Event, {async block@/Users/jack/.cargo/registry/src/rsproxy.cn-8f6827c7555bfaf8/async-stream-0.3.5/src/lib.rs:193:9: 193:59}>`

I know I could just switch to dynamic dispatch like this but I prefer static dispatch:
pub struct Feed {
    pub event_iterator: Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = Event> + Send + Sync>>,
}

// and box s
// ...striped
Self { event_iterator: Box::pin(s) }

Any way to resolve the error? I dont want to have the Box<dyn trait>.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78510132/5397009

The solution is to replace the T type parameter with a concrete type. Unfortunately you can't name the concrete type you're using because of the anonymous async block. On unstable, this can be fixed with an impl Trait alias as in the linked answer. On stable Rust, this requires quite a bit of boilerplate wrapping the anonymous async block in an explicit Future.

The proper way to convert an iterator to a stream is futures::stream::iter().
